# How to move the database from one server to another server?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2005

I attached the database in Windows authentication Mode, then it detach the database, and then i try to attach the same database in sql authentication mode. It showing error as "cannot create a sysindex"

The database was created in windows authentication mode, It is working in all windows authentication mode. It was not able to attach in SQL Server Authentication mode.

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of detaching the database, pause all transactions and backup the database. Restore it on other machine. That should work.

Comment: I do that all the time, the on thing you should note is if  you have restoring from a Full SQL to the express edition, you may need to turn the service off and set the service to "Local" from "Netowrk" when doing the restore, then after restoring set the service from "Local" to "Network"